# Error in Script File If I Restart Identifyer Column After Insert

Tags: java, hsqldb

Is it possible to restart the ID column of an HSQLDB after rows were inserted? Can I even set it to restart at a value lower than existing IDs in the table?

### The Situation

I have a simple Java program which connects to a HSQLDB like so:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:" + hsqldbPath, "", "");
```

This gives me an `HsqlException` when executing the following script (this is an excerpt, the complete script for HSQLDB 2.2.4 can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/2fbPYQDd)):

```
SET SCHEMA PUBLIC
CREATE MEMORY TABLE PUBLIC.MAP(
    ID BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    FOO VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL)
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.MAP ALTER COLUMN ID RESTART WITH 1
// [...]
SET SCHEMA PUBLIC
INSERT INTO MAP VALUES(1,'Foo')
INSERT INTO MAP VALUES(2,'Bar')
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.MAP ALTER COLUMN ID RESTART WITH 42
```

The message is:

```
HsqlException: error in script file: ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.MAP ALTER COLUMN ID RESTART WITH 42
```

The exception goes away when I move the `RESTART`-command before the `INSERT`s. The [documentation](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch09.html#alter_table-section) gives no hint as to why that would be necessary.

I will eventually have to make this work on version 2.2.4 but have the same problem with the current version 2.3.2.

### Background

What I am trying to do here is to recreate a situation which apparently occurred in production: An unlucky interaction with the database (I don't know what exactly happened) seems to have caused newly inserted rows to collide with existing ones because they were issued the same IDs. I want to create a test replicating the scenario in order to write a proper fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .script file of the database follows a predefined order for the statements. This shouldn't be altered if it is edited and only certain manual changes are allowed (see [the guide](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/deployment-chapt.html#dec_script_manual_change) for details).

You can execute the ALTER TABLE statement via JDBC at the start of your test instead of inserting it in the script.

If IDENTITY values for the PRIMARY KEY collide, you will get an exception when you insert the values.

The actual fix for a problem like this is to RESTART WITH the max value in the primary key column plus one.

Comment: Executing `ALTER TABLE ...` via JDBC worked, thanks. I silently expected that queries via JDBC and via script were treated identically. Could you link to a source for your (apparently correct) assumption that this is not the case?

Comment: See the HSQLDB Guide regarding alterations to the .script file.

Comment: I only found [this](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/deployment-chapt.html#dec_script_manual_change) which does limit the valid queries (and arguably bans mine because it "affect[s] the integrity of existing data") but does not back the universality of your statement. One of us could rephrase your first sentence and include the link. I will then accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think [SEQUENCES are much more flexible](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-identity-sequence-and-table-sequence-generator/)e than IDENTITY. The IDENTITY generator disabled JDBC batching, by the way.

But if you use SEQUENCE identifiers, you must pay attention to the [hilo optimizers](http://vladmihalcea.com/from-jpa-to-hibernates-legacy-and-enhanced-identifier-generators/) as well, because identifier are generated by Hibernate using a sequence value as a base calculation starting point.

With a SEQUENCE [the restart](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch09.html#alter_sequence-section) goes like this:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE my_seqeunce RESTART WITH 105;
```